# Resources.resx Error when dynamically changing background image

Tags: c#

I am trying to dynamically change the background image of a Windows Application Form C#
this is the code executed on `form_load`

```
  private void PSP_Manager_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        label2.Text = " " + Signin.SetValueForText1.ToString();
        PSP_Manager.ActiveForm.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"..psp\psp\Resources\PSPBlackBG.jpg");
        
    }
```

I am getting this error

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Invalid Resx file. Could not find file 'C:\Users\adoha\source\repos\psp\psp\Resources\57059791_385667318691952_5483239108757159936_n.jpg'. Line 126, position 5.    psp C:\Users\adoha\source\repos\psp\psp\Properties\Resources.resx   126
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear : Could not find file 'C:\Users\adoha\source\repos\psp\psp\Resources\57059791_385667318691952_5483239108757159936_n.jpg'

delete that image if you don't want it, or re-import it if you want it.

right-click in your project name  > choose "Open Folder in File Explorer" and check
"Resources" folder what images contain.

Comment: Thank you mate, I also had to delete all the data related to the image in the Resources.resx file